# how to pack a hosted webapp by cordova

Tags: cordova

I want to pack my webapp by using cordova.

My webapp follows SPA pattern.

So, is there any good solution to pack my webapp to native app refer to my website remote url.

and invoke like this `<script type="text/script" src="cordova.js"></script>`

then I can use Cordova API

Comment: You are very confused, you should read more about Cordova.

Comment: sorry. I used to set `<content src="https://my.site.fake">` in config.xml. when app opened,it turned to my website,but Cordova API can not use.